# What does the error "Parse issue: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier" really mean?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm dealing with a parsing issue in Xcode, one that triggers a failing issue, not a warning, and there is little or no information about this. It appears to be associated with LLVM, but since I am not a compiler person, what little technical documentation exists means nothing to me, and what non-technical answers exist does not help work around this.

I have gone into Organizer and deleted the derived data for this project, I have made sure all of the files that can be set to the target application are set, cleaned the project, searched (futiley) for 'type-name', etc. Still this error appears immediately upon opening the project. This appears to have started when I checked out the project onto a new machine today, but I didn't notice it until I went for a test build. Any ideas?

Not only am I looking for an answer to get me on my day, I am also looking for an explanation of the error so that I avoid it in the future. [There is a "duplicate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10419835/11976) but there is no useful answer to it, and nothing to explain what is really going on

Problem code is below, with the error flagged on the line `@interface OCSystemReportParser ()`.

Here is the header in question...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OCSystemReportParser : NSObject

- (void) parseSystemReports:(NSArray *)systemReports;

@end
```

...and the implementation in question...

```
#import "OCSystemReportParser.h"

/*
 System Report Keys
 */
NSString* const OCKeyApplications = @"Applications";
NSString* const OCKeyHardware = @"Hardware";
NSString* const OCKeyMemory = @"Memory";
NSString* const OCKeySoftware = @"Software";


/*
 Parsed Data Keys
 */

const NSString 

@interface OCSystemReportParser () // ERROR IS FLAGGED HERE

// keywords whose data we need
@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSArray *actionableKeywords;
// lines for the current report
@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSArray *reportSource;
// key-value pairs for the information in the system report
@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *parsedData;
// completed dictionaries of parsed reports
@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *completedReports;

@end

@implementation OCSystemReportParser

@synthesize actionableKeywords = _actionableKeywords;
@synthesize reportSource = _reportSource;
@synthesize parsedData = _parsedData;
@synthesize completedReports = _completedReports;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Object Lifecycle Stack
#pragma mark -

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark File Input Stack
#pragma mark -

/*
 Kicks off the process of data collection. This is the only public method.
 */
- (void) parseSystemReports:(NSArray *)systemReports {
    //NSLog(@"OCSystemReportParser:parseSystemReports:%@", systemReports);

    for ( NSString *path in systemReports ) {

        // reset the dictionary
        self.parsedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        // generate and parse the source data
        self.reportSource = [self createArrayWithReport:[self readReport:path]];
        //[self parseReport];

        // save the results
        [self.completedReports addObject:self.parsedData];
    }

    [self outputCompletedReports];

}

/* 
 returns a string of the content of the report file
 */
- (NSString *) readReport:(NSString *)path {
    //NSLog(@"OCSystemReportParser:readReport:%@", path);
    return nil;
}

/*
 returns an array containing the report data clean of empty lines and whitespace
 */
- (NSArray *) createArrayWithReport:(NSString *)reportData {
    //NSLog(@"OCSystemReportParser:createArrayWithReport:");
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Housekeeping Stack
#pragma mark -

/*
 Handles the initialization and population of helper data
 */

- (void) initializeKeyValues {
    //NSLog(@"OCSystemReportParser:initializeKeyValues:");
    self.actionableKeywords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:OCKeyApplications, OCKeyHardware, OCKeyMemory, OCKeySoftware, nil];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Data Parsing Stack
#pragma mark -

/*
 Kicks off the parsing of the strings in the report array
 */
- (void) parseReport {
    //NSLog(@"OCSystemReportParser:parseReport:");

}

/*
 Gets the computer type and user name from the header of the report
 */
- (void) parseUserInformation {
    //NSLog(@"OCSystemReportParser:parseUserInformation:");
    // information is in line 1
    // ComputerModel Firstname Lastname
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark File Output Stack
#pragma mark -

/*
 Kicks off the output process starting with the completed reports
 */
- (void) outputCompletedReports {
    //NSLog(@"OCSystemReportParser:outputCompletedReports:");

}
```

Comment: Side node: statements like `const NSString *OCKeyMemory...` should be `NSString* const OCKeyMemory...`. You want the `const` to apply to the pointer, not the NSString itself (which is already immutable).

Comment: @MattL Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const NSString 

@interface OCSystemReportParser () // ERROR IS FLAGGED HERE
```

The issue is that `const NSString` statement. It isn't valid, or terminated with a semicolon, so the compiler is saying that it cannot combine `@interface` with `const NSString` into something meaningful.

Comment: So, the parse issue is exactly what it says, then? it was trying to parse `const NSString @interface`, couldn't surmise what it was and returned a generic `'type-name'` as the "class" in question?

Comment: @PhilipRegan, that's correct. "type-name" is referring to `const NSString`.