# xCode iOS SDImagecache.h Error (Cannot combine with previous 'void' declaration s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get two errors the Code is my original one, i have the error message right below the code on both of them. Any help is appreciated.

```
- (void)removeImageForKey:(NSString *)key fromDisk:(BOOL)fromDisk withCompletition:(void void(^)(void))completion;
```

> Error Code : "Cannot combine with previous 'void' declaration
>   specifier"

I get that code, and also this code as the same error below :

```
- (void)clearDiskOnCompletion:(void void(^)(void))completion;
```

> Error "Cannot combine with previous 'void' declaration s"

If you want the full code for the header, you can view it on [Gitrepo for SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h).

Comment: doubt it has anything to do with SDWebImage. Error is somewhere else in your code. [See this question here for similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107932/4029561)

Comment: See the lines above and below the flagged files (The ones with redmarks indicating compile errors). Review the lines immediately above and below them. See if you have some invalid syntax there e.g. the word s without any semi colon etc.

Comment: @NSNoob i erased a void on both lines and now i have no error. Not sure if that helps i did alot of stuff with the code.

Comment: Mmhmm Okay. Btw is your SDWebImage updated? The method signature is different in the GitRepo. May have been some issue with your customization of SDWebImage (Judging by `I did a lot of stuff with the code`)